# Jordan normal form of $ A + \alpha I$

Tags: jordan-normal-form

Help me please,

I tried to prove, that JNF of matrix $ A + \alpha I$ is equal to matrix $ A_j + \alpha I$ where $A_j$ is JNF of A.

Is it true, that $ A_j + \alpha I$ - JNF by definition? Because, it is block diagonal matrix and every block are Jordan blocks.

Comment: Is $E$ the identity matrix? (!)

Comment: sorry, yes, E = drag(1,1,..,1)

Comment: Its name is $I$.

Comment: To finish it you must show that $A+\alpha I$ is similar to $A_j + \alpha I$.

Comment: and how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S^{-1}AS=B$ then $S^{-1}(A+\alpha I)S=S^{-1}AS+S^{-1}\alpha I S=B+\alpha I$.

If $B$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A$, then  by inspection $B+\alpha I$ is in Jordan canonical form, and hence is the Jordan canonical form of $A+\alpha I$.

Comment: thank you so much!